# Why are electrons negetively charged?

Tags: electricity, electrons, electric-current, charge, conventions

Why have we assigned a negative charge to electrons (and positive for protons)?

I feel it would be easier if electrons were positive (thereby, protons negative)- electrons would flow in the direction of current rather than flowing in the opposite direction. Something that would make more *natural* sense.

Is there is a historical reason or just something we have overlooked and now it's too late to change it?

Or is there a compelling reason for this choice that I could not find over the web?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on History of Science.

Comment: [Its a historical accident](https://xkcd.com/567/) There is no deeper reason

Comment: One random choice by Benjamin Franklin while dealing with static electricity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the charge naming convention wrong?](http://physics.stackexchange.com//17109/)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that all experiments known can be explained by having two types of electric charge. To distinguish between the two types of charge them it is necessary to introduce labels, conventionally the labels were taken be "positive" and "negative". Because of history, electrons are given the label "negative".